# Splitting file into parts for dictionary use

Tags: vb.net, split

I have an uploaded file, displaying

> Han 33.3
>   Han 5.66
>   Han 8.3
>   Chewbacca 99.4
>   Chewbacca 100.3
>   Chewbacca 98.1

I need to make an average for each han and Chewbacca using a dictionary, but first I have to split the list in order to do that.  How do I split them for this purpose.

Comment: really?  Hit [F2] then search for split

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that the whitespace between the name and quantity is a single space.  I'm also calling your values "scores" and Han and Chewbacca "players" for my example solution.  The result splits the line into individual key-value pairs; each key represents the list of values found; it:

Imports System.IO

```
Dim pathToYourFile As String = "Path to your file with file name"

Dim f As StreamReader = File.OpenText(pathToYourFile)
Dim fileText As String = f.ReadToEnd
f.Close()

Dim singleSpace As String = " "    'single space between quotes
Dim playerScores As New SortedDictionary(Of String, List(Of Double))
Dim lines() As String = fileText.Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray())
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim scoreLine() As String = lines(i).Split(" ".ToCharArray())
    Dim playerName As String = scoreLine(0)
    Dim score As Double = Double.Parse(scoreLine(1))

    If playerScores.ContainsKey(playerName) Then
        playerScores(playerName).Add(score)
    Else
        Dim list As New List(Of Double)
        list.Add(score)
        playerScores.Add(playerName, list)
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Class DataClass
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Value() As Decimal
End Class

' ...

Public Shared Function GetAverageDict(lines As IEnumerable(Of String)) _
                          As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
    Dim lst As New List(Of DataClass)()
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim lastSpaceIndex = line.LastIndexOf(" ")
        If (lastSpaceIndex >= 0) Then
            Dim name = line.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex).Trim()
            Dim value = Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1), _
                                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            lst.Add(New DataClass() With { .Name = name, .Value = value })
        End If
    Next
    Dim averages = From g In From x In lst _
                   Group x By key = x.Name _
                   Select New With { .Name = key, _ 
                                     .Average = Group.Average(Function(y) y.Value) }
    Return averages.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Name, Function(y) y.Average)
End Function
```

The function first gets the parts from each line. It assumes that the last space is the separator between the parts. This way, the name can also contain space characters.

The data is collected in a list that is afterwards grouped by the name. By calling `ToDictionary` the result of the grouping operation is converted in a dictionary.

Call the function like this:

```
Dim dict = GetAverageDict(System.IO.File.GetLines(filePath))
```